# VB.net add watermark to word doc

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, watermark

I am trying to use VB.NET to add a watermark to a Microsoft Word 2010 document using Word's built in watermarking tool located under Page Layout > Page Background > Watermark. I've done quite a bit of research on the topic but all results suggest using `AddTextEffect` to add some custom text to the header.

While this visually achieves the same result, it does not use the built in watermark function in Word. Because it ignores the built in watermarking function within Word I cannot use my program to delete/edit existing watermarks. Please let me know any advice you might have!

My current code:

```
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(file.FullName)
wordApp.Visible = True

        'Create watermark
        With wordDoc
            .Activate()
            .Sections(1).Range.Select()
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.SelectAll()
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, watermark, font, 1, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0).Select()
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = False
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = True
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(colorBox.BackColor.R, colorBox.BackColor.G, colorBox.BackColor.B)
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0.5
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = 315
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = True
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 130
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = -999995
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = -999995
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument
            .ActiveWindow.Document.Save()
        End With
```